# Is it ok to build architecture around regular creation/deletion of tables in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a messaging app, where all messages are arranged into seasons by creation time. There could be billions of messages each season. I have a task to delete messages of old seasons. I thought of a solution, which involves DynamoDB table creation/deletion like this:

1. Each table contains messages of only one season
2. When season becomes 'old' and messages no longer needed, table is deleted

Is it a good pattern and does it encouraged by Amazon?

ps: I'm asking, because I'm afraid of two things, met in different Amazon services -

1. In Amazon S3 you have to delete each item before you can fully delete bucket. When you have billions of items, it becomes a real pain.
2. In Amazon SQS there is a notion of 'unwanted behaviour'. When using SQS api you can act badly regarding SQS infrastructure (for example not polling messages) and thus could be penalized for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an acceptable design pattern, it actually follows a best practice put forward by the AWS team, but there are things to consider for your specific use case.

- AWS has a limit of 256 tables per region, but this can be raised.  If you are expecting to need multiple orders of magnitude more than this you should probably re-evaluate.
- You can delete a table a DynamoDB table that still contains records, if you have a large number of records you have to regularly delete this is actually a best practice by using a rolling set of tables
- Creating and deleting tables is an asynchronous operation so you do not want to have your application depend on the time it takes for these operations to complete.  Make sure you create tables well in advance of you needing them.  Under normal circumstances tables create in just a few seconds to a few minutes, but under very, very rare outage circumstances I've seen it take hours.

The DynamoDB best practices documentation on [Understand Access Patterns for Time Series Data states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns)...

> You can save on resources by storing "hot" items in one table with
>   higher throughput settings, and "cold" items in another table with
>   lower throughput settings. You can remove old items by simply deleting
>   the tables. You can optionally backup these tables to other storage
>   options such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). Deleting an
>   entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items
>   one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do
>   as many delete operations as put operations.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly acceptable to split your data the way you describe. You can delete a DynamoDB table regardless of its size of how many items it contains.

As far as I know there are no explicit SLAs for the time it takes to delete or create tables (meaning there is no way to know if it's going to take 2 seconds or 2 minutes or 20 minutes) but as long your solution does not depend on this sort of timing you're fine.

In fact the idea of sharding your data based on age has the potential of significantly improving the performance of your application and will definitely help you control your costs.